# Django Docstring implementation

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-class-based-views, docstring

I have a Django project, I'm putting comments and google-style docstrings for better understanding. My question is, Is it okay to mention other methods or classes in a docstring within a function or a class-based view? That's to say, something like this:

```
class SearchFoodView(ListView):
    """Display a list of foods based on search query.

    Returns:
        ListView: An instance of ListView with the paginated search results.

    Notes:
        Due to `show_foods()`, `show_by_category()`, and `SearchFoodView` using
        the same template (`products-list.html`) to display the list, the context
        variable name `page_obj` is utilized for consistency across the views.

    """
    model = Food
    template_name = 'foods/food_search.html'
    context_object_name = 'page_obj'
    paginate_by = 5
```

Specifically in the 'Notes' section, I'm explaining the reason behind naming the context_object_name as 'page_obj' to provide clarification. Is this a good or bad practice?, or should I consider mentioning it as a comment within the view instead? or somewhere else? I really need to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

I find it beneficial to use the docstring to explain the purpose and parts(argument, methods, exceptions etc) of a class, and a comment to explain a non-obvious part of the code.  This keeps the concerns separate and ties the code to the comment (useful if there are a lot of such 'notes').

Remember docstrings can be used to generate automatic documentation. This particular note wouldn't really be useful in that context when separated from the code itself.